# Find the string that was NOT chosen in python

Tags: python

I am trying to choose a random string from a list, then create a variable with the string that was not chosen.

```
import random

gamers = ["bob", "joe"]
winner = random.choice(gamers)
loser = #? what do I do now to get the loser
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `random.choice`, you could use `random.sample` and assign the `loser` together with the `winner` (credit to @Kraigolas for recognizing my previous error; thanks):

```
winner, loser = random.sample(gamers, k=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two elements in the list, you can use `random.shuffle` instead and just extract the two elements:

```py
gamers = ["bob", "joe"]
random.shuffle(gamers)
winner, loser = gamers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

gamers = ["bob", "joe"]
winner = random.choice(gamers)
print(winner)
gamers.remove(winner)

for loser in gamers:
        print(loser + " is a loser")
```

You can remove the winner with this `gamers.remove(winner)`